# silverlight 4 combox not binding c#

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight page that I bind a object to.

When I first load the page all the combo boxes fill and they show the correct selected item.
When I refresh the page the combo boxes still have their items but the selected value doesn't bind.

Bound using

```
SelectedValue="{Binding WriterID,Mode=TwoWay}"
Article.DataContext = ActiveArticle
```

Update:
It appears to be losing the databinding when I change the datacontext of the control
Any ideas why?

Comment: Losing the binding when changing the datacontext is a known problem. Unfortunately I don't have the reference to hand.

Comment: If you put this as the Aanswer, I will accept:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment this is a known problem. I haven't been able to find the reference I was looking for, but I found this [bug report on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/523394/silverlight-forum-combobox-selecteditem-binding)

The solution is to reset the binding expression when the selection changes. The code in the report does this in a subclassed `ComboBox` but if you are unable to override the `ComboBox` in your application you can do it in the view class.

```
public class XComboBox : ComboBox 
{ 
    private BindingExpression bE; 
    public XComboBox() 
    { 
        this.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(XComboBox_SelectionChanged); 
    } 

    void XComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (bE==null) 
        { 
         bE = this.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            if (this.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty) == null) 
            { 
             this.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, bE.ParentBinding);     
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```